# I am getting the error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: UnsupportedOperationError: sendKeysToActiveElement

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I used the below lines of code but i have been facing an issue.

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(control).keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).keyUp(protractor
.Key.CONTROL).perform().then(function());
```

Answer (score 1):

The Error **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning** occurs when there were missing some system packages to be able to run the particular action, also it depends on the browser you using to perform this action

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(control).keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL).perform().then(function());
```

So, the question you have asked requires some more information like:

Version: --?

OS Platform: --?

Browser: FF/chrome/IE?

Selenium/Protractor version: ?

few github issues are also logged for the same, have a look at their comment discussions, you might get some idea about it:
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1179
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5517